# unable to read Json object within AJAX call in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**Background:** I am working on a PHP-MVC web project, and in the home page, I am trying to get an interface, where in, on page load news feeds are displayed.
There is a text box provided where in we can enter the text and this will be taken as latest feed and persisted to DB via help of AJAX.

The interface looks similar to twitter WEB.

**Problem:** Now, keeping that objective, I have coded the following Js and controller files.
The issue I am facing is the received object/variable `latestComment` in JS is of type String but I am unable to retrieve the contents (it shows undefined) after parsing the received object.

Index.js

```
    $(function() {
    if ($('#comment_button').length !== 0) {

    / / On click of comment_button, newfeed
    //identifier data is sent to controller
    //'newfeed' is binded with a input type='text' in html
    //controller handles with postFeed($param) and persists data into DB
    //the return value from method is Json encoded Object to controller


  $('#comment_button').on('click', function() {
  var stringValue = $('#newfeed').val();
  //check if input data is not null
  if (stringValue) {
    $.ajax(url + "/home / postFeed / " + stringValue)
      .done(function(latestComment) {
        //but the recieved object 'latestComment' is of type string
        obj = jQuery.parseJSON(latestComment);
        $('#ajax-result-box').html('');
        var Str = '';
        $.each(obj, function(index, inVal) {
          Str += '<div class="jumbotron">Author:' + obj.author + '</div>';
        });
        $('#ajax-result-box').html(Str);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        // this will be executed if the ajax-call had failed
      })
      .always(function() {
        // this will ALWAYS be executed, regardless if the ajax-call was success or not
      });

  }
  //if input data is null
  else
    alert("
    Input Empty!!");

  });
  }
  });
```

home.php(controller)

```
public function postFeed($postFeedVal) 
    {
        //'postFeedVal' is the recieved input value from js file
        //Load Model and call its method,return json encoded 'latestcomment'
        //to javascript
        $feed_model = $this->loadModel('FeedModel');
        $feed_model->addFeeds($postFeedVal);
        $latestComment=$feed_model->getLastFeed();
        echo json_encode($latestComment);
    }
```

Comment: You are saying `obj` is `undefined`? I don't think that is even possible. Or are you saying `obj.author` is `undefined`? That's more likely, since your loop is strange. You are iterating over `obj`, but you are not doing anything with the loop variable. Maybe you actually want `inVal.author`? What is the value of `obj`?

Comment: Update with the json response. The JSON response will always be a string. That's why you are converting it to an object using `jQuery.parseJSON(latestComment);` Side note, if your server is not setting the header `Content-Type: application/json`, add `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax request.

Comment: @FelixKling You are right. ranjzz You actually need the value of inVal.author,not obj.author.

Comment: What is the output of the php function? Can you add a `console.log(latestComment)` just above `obj=...` and show the result?

Comment: @FelixKling  thank you for pointing out, i commited such a silly mistake, now it working...i replaced obj with inVal in $.each statement. :-)